# Why don't python dict keys/values quack like a duck?

Tags: python, language-design

Python is [duck typed](https://hackernoon.com/python-duck-typing-or-automatic-interfaces-73988ec9037f), and generally this avoids casting faff when dealing with primitive objects.

> The canonical example (and the reason behind the name) is the duck test: If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

However one notable exception is dict keys/values, which look like a duck and swim like a duck, but notably *do not quack like a duck*.

```
>>> ls = ['hello']
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> for key in d.keys():
..      print(key)
..
'foo'
>>> ls + d.keys()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_keys") to list
```

Can someone enlighten me as to why this is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: `ls + list(d.keys())`?

Comment: IIn older Python versions `dict.keys()` was a list but that changed and now it is a dict view object: From the help: `D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys`

Comment: Python makes it pretty clear it is not a list: `>>>d.keys()` returns `dict_keys(['foo'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an explicit check for `list` type (or its children) in python source code (so even `tuple` doesn't qualify):

```
static PyObject *
list_concat(PyListObject *a, PyObject *bb)
{
    Py_ssize_t size;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject **src, **dest;
    PyListObject *np;
    if (!PyList_Check(bb)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                  "can only concatenate list (not \"%.200s\") to list",
                  bb->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
```

so python can compute size very quickly and reallocate the result without trying all containers or iterate on the right hand to find out, providing very fast list addition.

```
#define b ((PyListObject *)bb)
    size = Py_SIZE(a) + Py_SIZE(b);
    if (size < 0)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    np = (PyListObject *) PyList_New(size);
    if (np == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

One way to workaround this is to use in-place extension/addition:

```
my_list += my_dict  # adding .keys() is useless
```

because in that case, in-place add iterates on the right hand side: so every collection qualifies.

(or of course force iteration of the right hand: `+ list(my_dict)`)

So it *could* accept any type but I suspect that the makers of python didn't find it worth it and were satisfied with a simple & fast implementation which is used 99% of the time.

Answer (score 8):

Dict keys actually implements the set's interface rather than the list's, so you can perform set operations with dict keys directly with other sets:

```
d.keys() & {'foo', 'bar'} # returns {'foo'}
```

But it doesn't implement the `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, and `insert` methods, which are required to "quack" like a list, so it cannot perform any of the list operations without being explicitly converted to a list first:

```
ls + list(d.keys()) # returns ['hello', 'foo']
```

Comment: but you cannot concatenate list + dict and dict implements `__getitem__`: `>>> d.__getitem__
<built-in method __getitem__ of dict object at 0x0000000002FD9048>`. The fact that `__getitem__` isn't defined isn't the reason.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: a dict lacks other Sequence methods that are required for an object to be treated as a list (e.g. `__reversed__`). The table at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc is a helpful reference.

Comment: if you check the source code, it's really more basic than that. it just _has_ to be a `list`

Comment: `PyList_Check`? Yeah you're right, I guess it is more basic in reality: CPython checks if the `Py_TPFLAGS_LIST_SUBCLASS` bit is set on the object type's `tp_flags`. So this answer addresses why a dict_keys object does quack like a list from an ABC perspective, but a more direct answer is probably that dict_keys does not inherit from list and fails `PyList_Check`.

Comment: so this highly voted answer is _wrong_. I guess people were impressed by the usage of dunder methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the definition of `d.keys()` the you can see the following.

```
def keys(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """ D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys """
    pass
```

Or use this statement:

```
print(d.keys.__doc__)
```

It clearly mentions that the output is `set-like` object.

Now you are trying to append a set to a list.

You need to convert the set into list and then append it.

```
x = ls + list(d.keys())
print(x)
# ['hello', 'foo']
```